# how to change the default save format of a worksheet from .xml to .xls in the "Save As" dialogue?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, interop, savefiledialog

i don't want to show the Save As dialog as soon as the worksheet opens i want to change the default format of the dialog in the menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT 2:

This code I've confirmed works:

```
        var xlsApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        xlsApp.Visible = true;
        xlsApp.DefaultSaveFormat = XlFileFormat.xlHtml;
```

---

EDIT:

To set the default format for saving files, application wide, you can use code similar to this:

```
 excelApp.DefaultSaveFormat = XlFileFormat.xlCSV //default save as csv
```

see:
[Application.DefaultSaveFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.defaultsaveformat.aspx) and [XlFileFormat Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlfileformat.aspx)

---

Call excelApp.GetSaveAsFilename()  You can pass the initial filename, a filefilter (this is what you want) etc.

Something like:

```
 .GetSaveAsFilename(FileFilter: "Xls Format (*.xls),*.xls")
```

I'm using .Net 4's optional parameters.  You may have to use it like:

```
 .GetSaveAsFilename(Type.Missing, "Xls Format (*.xls),*.xls", 
                    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.getsaveasfilename.aspx

Comment: nice method! but i asked how it can be done without the SaveAs dialog pop up in the beginning.. for some strange reason when i create my excel and i try to save it the default format is .xml
So how can i change it ???

Comment: Please see my updated answer.  That should answer your question.

Comment: no! :/ still nothing.. i was sure that this would be a nice clean solution but eventually it didn't work.. i tried every combination.. i even used it with mybook, still nothing. but thank you very much for your effort!

Comment: I just tested the code myself and it worked with several different FileFormats.  I've posted the example code I got it to work with.  There are *some* formats that it throws a COMException on, however.  I'm assuming that has to do with what excel version you have.  But they seem few and far between.

Comment: that's exactly how i try to do it.. once i make my excel application visible i set the format with the code you mention 
.DefaultSaveFormat = Excel.XlFileFormat.xlExcel9795;

Comment: Are you catching a comexception, or is it just not working?  If its not working, I'm not sure what to tell you.  That's the only way it can be done.  I suppose you could post some code.

Comment: @Iamnotadinosaur let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2042/discussion-between-chris-deneb-and-i-am-not-a-dinosaur)

Comment: ok i found another way to solve my problem. however your answer is correct for most normal cases, so i mark it as accepted! tnx anyway ;)

Answer (score 0):

Click the Microsoft Office Button on the top left corner of the page. Select "Excel Options" on the bottom of the menu. On the pop up page, click on “Save” on the left side. Use the pull down menu on the right to select the format you want as default and “Save.”

Comment: but i create my worksheet throut a program written in c#... i do not open manually excel... so with your way the next time the default format whould be the same... i need code! thanks anyway..